# OpenGL/GSL not working without setting Transpose to GL_TRUE

Tags: opengl, game-engine, glm-math, coordinate-transformation

GLM matrices doesnt seem to work without transfom

```
glm::mat4 proj = glm::ortho(0.0f,960.0f,0.0f,540.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);
```

`GL_TRUE` has to be set :

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(GetUniformLocation(name),1 ,GL_TRUE,&matrix[0][0])
```

isn't GLM already suppose to be in column major form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't wan to transpose the matrix, then ythe vector has to be multiplied to the matrix from the **right** in the shader code:

```
mat4 transformation;
vec4 vertexPosition;

gl_Position = transformation * vertexPosition;
```

---

**Explanation**:

See [GLSL Programming/Vector and Matrix Operations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Vector_and_Matrix_Operations):

> Furthermore, the *-operator can be used for matrix-vector products of the corresponding dimension, e.g.:
>
> ```
> vec2 v = vec2(10., 20.);
> mat2 m = mat2(1., 2.,  3., 4.);
> vec2 w = m * v; // = vec2(1. * 10. + 3. * 20., 2. * 10. + 4. * 20.)
> ```
>
> **Note that the vector has to be multiplied to the matrix from the right**.
>   
>   If a vector is multiplied to a matrix from the left, the result corresponds to to multiplying a column vector to the transposed matrix from the right. This corresponds to multiplying a column vector to the transposed matrix from the right:
>   Thus, multiplying a vector from the left to a matrix corresponds to multiplying it from the right to the transposed matrix:
>
> ```
> vec2 v = vec2(10., 20.);
> mat2 m = mat2(1., 2.,  3., 4.);
> vec2 w = v * m; // = vec2(1. * 10. + 2. * 20., 3. * 10. + 4. * 20.)
> ```

**This means**:

If a matrix is defined like this:

```
mat4 m44 = mat4(
    vec4( Xx, Xy, Xz, 0.0),
    vec4( Yx, Xy, Yz, 0.0),
    vec4( Zx  Zy  Zz, 0.0),
    vec4( Tx, Ty, Tz, 1.0) );
```

And the matrix uniform `mat4 transformation` is set like this (see [`glUniformMatrix4fv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml):

```
glUniformMatrix4fv( .... , 1, GL_FALSE, &(m44[0][0] );
```

Then that the vector has to be multiplied to the matrix from the **right**:

```
gl_Position = transformation * vertexPosition;
```

But of course, the matrix can be set up *transposed*:

```
mat4 m44 = mat4(
    vec4(  Xx,  Yx,  Zx,  Tx),
    vec4(  Xy,  Yy,  Zy,  Ty),
    vec4(  Xz   Yz   Zz,  Tz),
    vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) );
```

**Or** can be transposet when set to the uniform variable:

```
glUniformMatrix4fv( .... , 1, GL_TRUE, &(m44[0][0] );
```

Then that the vector has to be multiplied to the matrix from the **left**:

```
gl_Position = vertexPosition * transformation;
```

Note, that the [glm API documentation](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.8/api/index.html) refers to [The OpenGL Shading Language specification 4.20](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.20.pdf).